# sublime - save all open/loaded files that have names?

Tags: python, sublimetext2

In Sublime Text 2, I want to be able to save all open/loaded files that have names.

I like how Sublime can have files with filenames, and have files that were never saved, and can be closed and it remembers about the untitled files and reloads them without me having to save them.
But when a file has a filename and has some changes in the buffer not yet saved, sublime shows it as such, with the filename and circle, I close sublime, and reopen it, I sublime has remebered it as it was and so the changes are still not saved to the file. That's great.. But.. I'd like a command to save all, but not the untitled ones.

There is a save all option in the menu, but it pops up a dialog box asking regarding saving of untitled files.

What API functions would be involved to write a command that leaves the untitled ones as is, and saves the ones with filenames?  (and is there any example code I can run that uses those API functions?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK, an opened file is represented by one or more views. So try to get all views and save those with file names. I wrote a simple example. Hope it can help you.

By the way, you can check all API's via the following link.

[Sublime Text 2 API Reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html)

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SaveAllExistingFilesCommand(sublime_plugin.ApplicationCommand):
    def run(self):
        for w in sublime.windows():
            self._save_files_in_window(w)

    def _save_files_in_window(self, w):
        for v in w.views():
            self._save_exiting_file_in_view(v)

    def _save_exiting_file_in_view(self, v):
        if v.file_name():
            if v.is_dirty():
                v.run_command("save")
```

Comment: thanks, just tried entering that, though that run like doesn't work with view.run_command('..')  a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532204/in-sublime-why-is-def-run-working-in-one-case-and-not-another-caseand-how-can   in the meantime i'll try a binding.

Comment: @barlop It is an `ApplicationCommand`, so you couldn't run it within a view. You can use keymap or change `ApplicationCommand` to `TextCommand` and change `run(self)` to `run(self, edit)` accordingly.

Comment: thanks, I see your code works very nicely. i'll give that ApplicationCommand->TextCommand a go too tomorrow.

Comment: Be great if I could launch it from command line. here's a related question that may be well within your extensive knowledge!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880055/run-a-sublime-plugin-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 7):

lhuang's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19516653/1426065) is fantastic, and does exactly what I think you want it to do. Make sure you save the plugin as `Packages/User/save_all_existing_files.py` in order for it to work properly. You can reach the `Packages` directory via the `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` menu item. I do have a few additions to make your life a little easier, though - a menu item and a key combination.

You generally shouldn't edit anything in the `Packages/Default` directory, as all the files can be overridden/expanded upon, but in this case I recommend it for aesthetics sake. Open `Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu` and add the following line right after line 128, which should be the `save_all` menu item:

```json
{ "command": "save_all_existing_files", "caption": "Save All Named Files", "mnemonic": "F" },
```

This will add a "Save All Named Files" option to the `File` menu. Next, go to `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User` and add the following line:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+s"], "command": "save_all_existing_files" },
```

If this file doesn't have any other contents, surround the above line with square brackets `[ ]` and remove the trailing comma, otherwise Sublime will complain at you.

Once the keymap file is saved, you can trigger the command by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. Obviously, you can change the keys if you don't like them. If you pick a combination that gives weird behavior, check out the [`FindKeyConflicts`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/FindKeyConflicts) plugin by @skuroda - it's invaluable for troubleshooting your setup, and especially when developing your own packages.

Good luck!

Comment: yes it looks good, I haven't voted or accepted anything yet 'cos I haven't had a chance to try it out, but I can see it looks good.  thanks for your additions too. i've just been out for hours without a laptop with a good battery.

Comment: thanks, great addition to the file menu. The binding for save_all_existing_files  doesn't look like a good choice though as with it one has to do ctrl-s twice to save normally. With that ctrl-s ctrl-n binding, if one just does ctrl-s for a regular save, it doesn't respond, I think it wants to know if one is going to do a ctrl-n afterwards.

Comment: @barlop you're right, I noticed the same thing as well. Try `"ctrl+alt+shift+s"` and it should work better. I just updated my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Instead of adding to the existing `Main.sublime-menu` file, I created a new one in the `Packages/User/` folder and it will show up at the bottom of the file items. Here are the contents of that file. `[
    {
        "caption": "File",
        "mnemonic": "F",
        "id": "file",
        "children":
        [
            { "command": "save_all_existing_files", "caption": "Save All Existing Files", "mnemonic": "x" },
        ]
    }
]`

Answer (score 1):

Just add the next line to the `Preferences > Key Bindings - User`

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+s"], "command": "save_all" }
```

`super` is a Command key in OS X. Use `ctrl` on Windows.

Comment: The person wants any valid files with names to be saved. ST fails to do this when there's an untitled doc open.