# How to run WindowCommand plugin from `sublime console`

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I created plugin for `sublime text 3` with 3 commands:
2 of them are of type `TextCommand`, one of them is `WindowCommand`

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class simple_text_pluginCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):      
        print("Hello World simple_text_plugin")
class simple_text_plugin2Command(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):      
        print("Hello World simple_text_plugin2")        
class simple_window_pluginCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):      
        print("Hello World simple_window_plugin")
```

Why I can call from `sublime command line` (ctrl + `) only text commands:

```
>>> view.run_command('simple_text_plugin') 
Hello World simple_text_plugin

>>> view.run_command('simple_text_plugin2') 
Hello World simple_text_plugin2
```

But cannot call `window` command:

```
>>> view.run_command('simple_window_plugin')
```

Got no output. How to run `Window` type plugin from `sublime console`?

Comment: Use `window.run_command("simple_window_plugin")`. Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532204/in-sublime-why-is-def-run-working-in-one-case-and-not-another-case-and-how-can/19533899#19533899.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `ApplicationCommand`: `sublime.run_command('application_command_name')`. Check `run_command` function for `sublime` module in the [API reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html).
- `WindowCommand`: `window.run_command('window_command_name')`. Check `run_command` method of [`sublime.Window`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.Window).
- `TextCommand`: `view.run_command('text_command_name')`. Check `run_command` method of [`sublime.View`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.View).