# Scripting find & replace operations in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2

Often I find myself doing repetitive file & replace operations in a file. Most often that comes down to *fixed* find and replace operations; deleting some lines, changing some strings that are always the same and so on.

In Vim that is a no-brainer,

```
function! Modify_Strength_Files()
    execute':%s/?/-/'
    execute':%s/Ä/-/'
    "--------------------------------------------------------
    execute':%s/Ä/-/'
    execute':%s///g'
    "--------------------------------------------------------
    execute':g/Version\ of\ Light\ Ship/d'
    execute':g/Version\ of\ Data\ for\ Specific\ Regulations/d'
    "--------------------------------------------------------
    " execute':g/LOADING\ CONDITION/d'
    " execute':g/REGULATION:\ A\.562\ IMO\ Resolution/d'

    " This is to reduce multiple blank lines into one.
    execute ':%s/\s\+$//e'
    execute ':%s/\n\{3,}/\r\r/e'
    " ---------------------
endfunction
```

copied verbatim.

How could a function like this be defined in Sublime Text editor, if it can be done at all, and then called to act upon the currently opened file?

Comment: Could you please try to record a macro?

Comment: @lhuang - How would that help?

Comment: @Idigas My bad. It seems that macro couldn't record replace command correctly. Maybe you have to write a plugin to do this.

Comment: @lhuang - Well, I am trying to write (something) to do this. Since ST has no similar scripting functionality as Vim, I assume I will have to dig down into python, write a function there and somehow "connect it" to the currently opened file. Help on how to do that is why I'm asking this.

Answer (score 14):

Here are resources to write Sublime Text 2 plugins:

1. [Sublime Text 2 API Reference](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html)
2. [Sublime Text 2 Plugin Examples](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/plugin-examples)
3. [How to run Sublime Text 2 commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532204/in-sublime-why-is-def-run-working-in-one-case-and-not-another-case-and-how-can/19533899#19533899)
4. [Setting up Sublime Text 2 Custom Keyboard Shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/492021/setting-up-sublime-text-2-custom-keyboard-shortcuts)

Example: you can write a similar plugin and bind a hot key to it, that is, `batch_edit` command. Then you can open a file and execute the command via that hot key. By the way, in this script, I didn't consider the file encoding. You can get the file encoding via `self.view.encoding()`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sublime, sublime_plugin

import re

class BatchEditCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self._edit = edit
        self._replace_all(r"\?", "-")
        self._replace_all(u"Ä", "-")
        self._delete_line_with(r"Version of Light Ship")
        self._delete_line_with(r"Version of Data for Specific Regulations")
        self._replace_all(r"(\n\s*\n)+", "\n\n")

    def _get_file_content(self):
        return self.view.substr(sublime.Region(0, self.view.size()))

    def _update_file(self, doc):
        self.view.replace(self._edit, sublime.Region(0, self.view.size()), doc)

    def _replace_all(self, regex, replacement):
        doc = self._get_file_content()
        p = re.compile(regex, re.UNICODE)
        doc = re.sub(p, replacement, doc)
        self._update_file(doc)

    def _delete_line_with(self, regex):
        doc = self._get_file_content()
        lines = doc.splitlines()
        result = []
        for line in lines:
            if re.search(regex, line, re.UNICODE):
                continue
            result.append(line)
        line_ending = {
            "Windows" : "\r\n",
            "Unix"    : "\n",
            "CR"      : "\r"
        }[self.view.line_endings()]
        doc = line_ending.join(result)
        self._update_file(doc)
```

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` looks like an [Emacs file variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) comment. 

Comment: It helped me, to know that the example script above should be saved under Sublimetext-Config -> Packages/User/ as link 2 described