# Perl Regular Expression Syntax from the Boost library

Tags: regex, boost

I would like to make a following replace operation in `Sublime Text` (uses Perl Regular Expression Syntax).

`I would loe [BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]ve to play with you`

should become

`I would love to play with you`

So for every `[BACKSPACE]` I want to remove one `[BACKSPACE]` and one character in front of it.

There's a problem: it is possible they will interract with each other:

`I would loe [BACKSPACE][BACKSPACE]ve to play with you`

will become

`I would loe [BACKSPACEve to play with you`

if we use `.\[BACKSPACE\]` regex. I assume it would work as normal coding is sequential and goes line by line.

How do I write such regex?

Comment: couldn't understand you. you need to learn how to ask first.

Comment: What does `boost` tag have in common with the question?

Comment: I don't understand why you couldn't understand my request when I even gave a clear example HuStmpHrrr.

Also the boost tag is related to the boost library which is necessary because if the expression is in any other library I cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

This task essentially needs counting. a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> language [is not regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Examples), and that's one you need here. So, at least from theoretical point of view, regular expressions cannot help you.

But in practice theory differs from practice.

1. You can just replace `.(?<!\[BACKSPACE\])\[BACKSPACE\]` with empty string several times over the document, until it doesn't change your document. (That's a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).)
2. Real-world regular expressions engines have some metasymbols that are not regular, e.g. backreferences. Probably, there's a way to use these.
3. You can always mix regular expressions with ordinary code, or just write the plain code. This task is not that much complex.

As you're using Sublime, you might be interested in its [scripting API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971938/scripting-find-replace-operations-in-sublime-text).

As for the knowledge of regular expressions, try reading J. Friedl's *Regular expressions* book. It has a wide and consistent coverage of the topic.