# Run a sublime plugin from the command line?

Tags: sublimetext2

how can I run a sublime plugin from the command line?

I have read of a `subl --command` but it seems to be for osx and i'm on windows.  http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html I see nothing there to call a plugin,  and the commands don't seem to work for sublime_text.exe

i'm on Windows, with sublime_text.exe

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text plugins do not offer command line interfaces.

Many times Sublime Text plugins wrap an external command (csslint, jshint, etc.) which is run as a subprocess by the plugin. Because your question does not specify which plugin you want to run it is impossible to tell whether or not this plugin is based on an external program.

I'd rather suggest you to ask your question in more sense "How do I solve problem X from the command line" as it sounds you are approaching the problem from the wrong angle.

Comment: the plugin is a py or rather, pyc file that doesn't make any external calls and is run by a keybinding from within sublime. it just uses the sublime api. sublime loads it when it starts and loads all the pyc files and runs it when requested using the keybinding I assigned it. Does that clarify?